# Reading Geotag data from image in php

Tags: php, geolocation

Does anyone know if there is a way to read geotag data from photos in PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 23):

Like everyone else has said, exif_read_data(); will do it.
To go ahead and get all of the data, use these args:

```
exif_read_data($img, 0, true); // where $img is the path to your image
```

This function can only read headers from tiffs and jpegs and I'm pretty sure only jpegs may contain geotags. I've written a simple php script for use in the command line and posted it as a [gist on github](https://gist.github.com/1545406).

Run the script like this: php exif.php

It will echo out an array. Look for the coordinates here:

```
[GPS] => Array
    [GPSLatitudeRef] => N
    [GPSLatitude] => Array
        [0] => 30/1
        [1] => 1589/100
        [2] => 0/1
    [GPSLongitudeRef] => W
    [GPSLongitude] => Array
        [0] => 87/1
        [1] => 3609/100
        [2] => 0/1
    [GPSAltitudeRef] => 
    [GPSAltitude] => 18289/454
    [GPSTimeStamp] => Array
    [0] => 20/1
    [1] => 22/1
    [2] => 2065/1
    [GPSImgDirectionRef] => T
    [GPSImgDirection] => 34765/689
```

The Latitude and Longitude arrays contain three values: 0 is for degrees, 1 is for minutes and 2 is for seconds.  If you see something like "1589/100" this is equal to 15.89. So for the GPSLongitude array, 3609/100 is equal to 36.09.

Convert the coordinates from degrees-minutes-second form to decimal form here http://www.satsig.net/degrees-minutes-seconds-calculator.htm

If the latitude is South, dont forget to make it negative. If the longitude is west, make that negative.  The coodinates from the above data are: 30.26483, -87.6015

Comment: I have a probably basic addition to the question.  How do you get php to "do" that math?  That is making 3609/100 equal 36.09

Comment: @LOlliffe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927475/php-format-latitude-and-longitude-with-degrees-minuets-and-seconds

Comment: git hub link gives me a 404

Answer (score 22):

[Will Coughlin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8691972/608624)'s answer is correct though I formulated a function for quick reference in case someone stumbles upon the same problem.

```
/**
 * Returns an array of latitude and longitude from the Image file
 * @param image $file
 * @return multitype:number |boolean
 */
function read_gps_location($file){
    if (is_file($file)) {
        $info = exif_read_data($file);
        if (isset($info['GPSLatitude']) && isset($info['GPSLongitude']) &&
            isset($info['GPSLatitudeRef']) && isset($info['GPSLongitudeRef']) &&
            in_array($info['GPSLatitudeRef'], array('E','W','N','S')) && in_array($info['GPSLongitudeRef'], array('E','W','N','S'))) {

            $GPSLatitudeRef  = strtolower(trim($info['GPSLatitudeRef']));
            $GPSLongitudeRef = strtolower(trim($info['GPSLongitudeRef']));

            $lat_degrees_a = explode('/',$info['GPSLatitude'][0]);
            $lat_minutes_a = explode('/',$info['GPSLatitude'][1]);
            $lat_seconds_a = explode('/',$info['GPSLatitude'][2]);
            $lng_degrees_a = explode('/',$info['GPSLongitude'][0]);
            $lng_minutes_a = explode('/',$info['GPSLongitude'][1]);
            $lng_seconds_a = explode('/',$info['GPSLongitude'][2]);

            $lat_degrees = $lat_degrees_a[0] / $lat_degrees_a[1];
            $lat_minutes = $lat_minutes_a[0] / $lat_minutes_a[1];
            $lat_seconds = $lat_seconds_a[0] / $lat_seconds_a[1];
            $lng_degrees = $lng_degrees_a[0] / $lng_degrees_a[1];
            $lng_minutes = $lng_minutes_a[0] / $lng_minutes_a[1];
            $lng_seconds = $lng_seconds_a[0] / $lng_seconds_a[1];

            $lat = (float) $lat_degrees+((($lat_minutes*60)+($lat_seconds))/3600);
            $lng = (float) $lng_degrees+((($lng_minutes*60)+($lng_seconds))/3600);

            //If the latitude is South, make it negative. 
            //If the longitude is west, make it negative
            $GPSLatitudeRef  == 's' ? $lat *= -1 : '';
            $GPSLongitudeRef == 'w' ? $lng *= -1 : '';

            return array(
                'lat' => $lat,
                'lng' => $lng
            );
        }           
    }
    return false;
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Call this function with filename. I testet it and it works prefectly.

Call example:

```
$fileName='xxxxxx'; //or $fileName='xxxxxxxxx';
echo $returned_data = triphoto_getGPS($fileName);
```

Function:

```
function triphoto_getGPS($fileName)
{
    //get the EXIF all metadata from Images
    $exif = exif_read_data($fileName);
    if(isset($exif["GPSLatitudeRef"])) {
        $LatM = 1; $LongM = 1;
        if($exif["GPSLatitudeRef"] == 'S') {
            $LatM = -1;
        }
        if($exif["GPSLongitudeRef"] == 'W') {
            $LongM = -1;
        }

        //get the GPS data
        $gps['LatDegree']=$exif["GPSLatitude"][0];
        $gps['LatMinute']=$exif["GPSLatitude"][1];
        $gps['LatgSeconds']=$exif["GPSLatitude"][2];
        $gps['LongDegree']=$exif["GPSLongitude"][0];
        $gps['LongMinute']=$exif["GPSLongitude"][1];
        $gps['LongSeconds']=$exif["GPSLongitude"][2];

        //convert strings to numbers
        foreach($gps as $key => $value){
            $pos = strpos($value, '/');
            if($pos !== false){
                $temp = explode('/',$value);
                $gps[$key] = $temp[0] / $temp[1];
            }
        }

        //calculate the decimal degree
        $result['latitude']  = $LatM * ($gps['LatDegree'] + ($gps['LatMinute'] / 60) + ($gps['LatgSeconds'] / 3600));
        $result['longitude'] = $LongM * ($gps['LongDegree'] + ($gps['LongMinute'] / 60) + ($gps['LongSeconds'] / 3600));
        $result['datetime']  = $exif["DateTime"];

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect Worked......This function returns all of the possible latitude ,langitude and datetime at what time photo taken...Note.* Location should be own while capturing the images..in this case only latitude and longitude will be shown otherwise not....If any issue ask..or let me know..i will help out.....

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [EXIF functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exif.php) of PHP:

```
exif_read_data($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`exif_read_data()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) function if the geotag data is embedded in the EXIF data.

Answer (score 0):

Install `Intervention\Image` by following command.

Reference: http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation

`composer require intervention/image`

Update `config/app.php`

`'providers' => [
    Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
],
'aliases' => [
    'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
]`

Use Library:

`$data = Image::make(public_path('IMG.jpg'))->exif();
if(isset($data['GPSLatitude'])) {
    $lat = eval('return ' . $data['GPSLatitude'][0] . ';')
        + (eval('return ' . $data['GPSLatitude'][1] . ';') / 60)
        + (eval('return ' . $data['GPSLatitude'][2] . ';') / 3600);
    $lng = eval('return ' . $data['GPSLongitude'][0] . ';')
        + (eval('return ' . $data['GPSLongitude'][1] . ';') / 60)
        + (eval('return ' . $data['GPSLongitude'][2] . ';') / 3600);
    echo "$lat, $lng";
} else {
    echo "No GPS Info";
}`