# Converting DDM to DEC (Decimal degrees)

Tags: php, coordinates, geo, degrees

I have a set of coordinates in the format DDM (Degrees decimal minutes), that i need to convert to decimal degrees.
From the function found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927475/php-format-latitude-and-longitude-with-degrees-minuets-and-seconds) i can convert DMS, but i have failed to find a function or formula that will allow me to change DDM into DEC.

For example the coordinate could be:

64 Degrees 0 Minutes N, 22 Degrees 33 Minutes W

From the conversion tool [here](http://www.pgc.umn.edu/tools/conversion) i know that the result is: 64, -22,55

So the question is how can I convert the DDM format ?

EDIT:

The data comes from a table that looks like this:

```
[Latitude_degrees]: 64
[Latitude_minutes]: 0
[Latitude_hemisphere]: N
[Longitude_degrees]: 22
[Longitude_minutes]: 33
[Longitude_hemisphere]: W
```

Comment: Do you literally have a string value of "64 Degrees 0 Minutes N, 22 Degrees 33 Minutes W"? If so, you need to extract the digits, and the N/S and E/W (easily done using sscanf or regexps).... that's your starting point; then it's all simple mathematics

Comment: The data comes from a table that looks like this:

[Latitude_degrees] [Latitude_minues] [Latitude_hemisphere]
64,0,N
[Longitude_degrees] [Longitude_minutes] [Longitude_hemisphere]
22,33,W

Comment: Then it's simple mathematics: `Latitude = Latitude_degrees + Latitude_minutes / 60` and if `Latitude_hemisphere = 'S'` then `Latitude = -Latitude`.... and the equivalent for Longitude

Comment: That does seem to work. 
Could you put that in an answer, and thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple mathematics

As pseudocode:

```
Latitude = Latitude_degrees + Latitude_minutes / 60 
if Latitude_hemisphere = 'S' then 
    Latitude = -Latitude
```

and the equivalent for Longitude