# How to convert coordinates into latitude and longitude in php (laravel)?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, coordinates, latitude-longitude

My coordinates are in this format:

> "3945N 02001E"
>
> "4007N 02013E"
>
> "4043N 01957E"

and I want to convert into latitudes and longitudes like that

> "lat" => 51.23570538029149,
>               "lng" => 4.429959780291502
>
> "lat" => 51.23570538029149,
>               "lng" => 4.429959780291502
>
> "lat" => 51.23570538029149,
>               "lng" => 4.429959780291502

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/spatie/geocoder

Comment: Hello..! I write this as a comment since I have never done something alike before. After a Google search on "php geography", "php geography library" if find a intersting package. It is the Laravel-Geographical package. Or you could mean something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927475/php-format-latitude-and-longitude-with-degrees-minuets-and-seconds that makes this question a duplicate.

Comment: @BenM I actually tried this link [https://github.com/laravie/geotools] but I don't think so it works properly for me

Answer (score 1):

you can use http://proj4js.org/ library  to convert lat

in php backend can use [this](http://packagist.org/packages/proj4php/proj4php)

also you can create your own api with [this](http://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=3857&x=161.8787481&y=34.1226300)  site

```
http://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=3857&x=161.8787481&y=34.1226300
```

Comment: Bro, Actually I don't have any idea how to use this in laravel  http://proj4js.org/  because it's a javascript library

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/proj4php/proj4php is the php implementation of this js package

Answer (score 1):

There is this web service that will do it for you:

[3945N 02001E](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/docs/support/guide-coordinate-systems-great-britain.pdf)
[4007N 02013E](https://www.bgs.ac.uk/data/webservices/CoordConvert_LL_BNG.cfc?method=BNGtoLatLng&easting=02013&northing=4007)

This is a good document that explains it all:
[coordinate systems pdf](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/docs/support/guide-coordinate-systems-great-britain.pdf)