# DD MM.MMM coordinates to Decimal in PHP

Tags: php, coordinates, openstreetmap

for using an Openstreetmap API I need to convert DDM coordinates to Decimal (DD) , but I can't find a solution on internet.

Example: I want to convert "N51°8.080, E11°33.313" to "51.134664 11.555220".

I just tried something like:

```
$longitude = $degreesLong+((($minutesLong*60)+($secondsLong))/3600);
$latitude = $degreesLat + ((($minutesLat * 60) + ($secondsLat)) / 3600);
```

But this formule is not correct...

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927475/php-format-latitude-and-longitude-with-degrees-minuets-and-seconds

Comment: Something like: $longitude = $degreesLong+((($minutesLong*60)+($secondsLong))/3600);
            $latitude = $degreesLat + ((($minutesLat * 60) + ($secondsLat)) / 3600);

Answer (score 0):

After looking hard on the web I found the following solution:

```
 // converts DD°MM.mmm to DD coordinates
public function ConvertToDecimal($cmbs){

    $convertedArray = [];
    
    foreach ($cmbs as $cmb) {

        // degrees
        $degreesLong = substr($cmb->longitude, 1, 1);
        $degreesLat = substr($cmb->latitude, 1, 2);

        // minutes and seconds
        $msLong = str_replace('.','',substr($cmb->longitude, 5, 6));
        $msLat = str_replace('.','',substr($cmb->latitude, 6, 7));

        // converted latitude
        $latitude = ($msLat/60);
        // if below 100 then add zero
        $latitude <100 ? $extra = '.0' :  $extra = '.';
        $latitude = str_replace('.', '',$latitude);
        $latitude = $degreesLat . $extra .$latitude;

        // converted longitude
        $longitude = ($msLong/60);
        // if below 100 then add zero
        $longitude <100 ? $extra = '.0' :  $extra = '.';
        $longitude = str_replace('.', '',$longitude);
        $longitude = $degreesLong . $extra .$longitude;

         array_push($convertedArray, [
            'name' => $cmb->name, 'lng' => $longitude, 'lat' => $latitude, 'gc_code' => $cmb->gc_code,
          'picture' => $cmb->picture]);

    }
    
    return $convertedArray;
}
```

If someone knows a shorter/better way, just post!