# Latitude and longitude from hexadecimal value

Tags: php, binary, hex, decimal, latitude-longitude

Hi I need to convert the response value from a GPS tracker to latitude and longitude.The response value is in Hexadecimal format and the document says the latitude and longitude will be `measured in degrees with a 1x10^-7 degree lsb, signed 2’s complement`. For example:

```
Hexa      Binary                              decimal        longitude
B9DCF6B1  10111001110111001111011010110001    3118266033    -117.6701263
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem using php.

Comment: Is your problem the PHP programming, or the algorithm to convert GPS data to L/L?

Comment: @ring0  need the alogorthm using php.Can you help me?

Comment: @SujathanR Refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19420991/608624 hope it helps

Comment: If you show the algorithm and an excerpt of what you did in PHP, we can help you. Sorry but implementing everything from scratch is a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19408899/222758) to PHP:

```
function convert($hex)
{
    $dec = hexdec($hex);
    return ($dec < 0x7fffffff) ? $dec * 0.0000001
                               : 0 - (0xffffffff - $dec) * 0.0000001;
}
```

Testing:

```
var_dump(convert('B9DCF6B1')); // float(-117.6701262)
```

Answer (score 0):

**The following python3 code will produce the desired output**

***If app is saved as main.py, type the following into the terminal***

> ./main.py B9DC F6B1

```
import sys


def hexToDecimal(hexCoord):
    base16INT = int(hexCoord, 16)
    print("HEX to decimal --->", base16INT)
    if base16INT >= (2 ** 32 / 2):
        return ((base16INT - 2 ** 32))
    else:
        return (base16INT)

def check_32_bit(n):
    return n<1<<31

def display_input_error(errorStr: str):
    print(errorStr)
    sys.exit()

def isValidHex(instr: str):
    try:
        int(sys.argv[1], 16)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def checkValidInput(param1, param2):
    if (not isValidHex(param1)) or (not isValidHex(param2)):
        display_input_error("Non-valid HEX input values")
    if (len(param1) != 4) or (len(param2) !=4):
        display_input_error("Both input Hex values MUST be four characters in length")
        return


def main():
    checkValidInput(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
    a: str = sys.argv[1]
    b: str = sys.argv[2]
    print("Input parameters: ", a, b)

    c = a+b
    decimalVal = hexToDecimal(c)
    print(decimalVal/1e7, "--->", decimalVal, "\"expressed as 1x10^-7 degree lsb\"")
    floatVal = float(decimalVal)
    floatVal = (floatVal/30000.00)
    intBase = int(floatVal)
    deg = int(intBase/60)
    mins = intBase-(deg*60)
    secs = int((floatVal-intBase)*60)
    outstr = str(deg) + "° " + str(mins) + "\" " + str(secs) + "\'"
    print("Output:",outstr)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

** Begin sample Output

> ```
> Input parameters:  B9DC F6B1
> HEX to decimal ---> 3118266033
> -117.6701263 ---> -1176701263 "expressed as 1x10^-7 degree lsb"
> Output: -653° -43" -22
> ```

** END of Output